# Why is boost::thread::join seemingly so expensive?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I just recently started working with multithreading with `boost::thread`, and I'm still a little unclear about some details, but from what I understand, `thread::join` is used when you want the 'parent' thread to block and wait for the thread to finish (I'm sure there's more to it than that, but I believe that is one use).

In the program I'm working on, I have a thread load a bunch of resources, and then in the last line, set its status to 'finished'. The main thread waits for this status and then calls `join`, but it seems to take about 2 seconds for it to unblock.

Is there a reason for this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you wait for the status to become 'finish' ?

Comment: @nos: I forgot to mention that I'm using a threaded class, and it has a member variable which stores the status, and the main thread checks that status. That part seems to be working fine. The main thread gets the updated status quickly, but when it calls join, it halts for a bit.

Comment: Well, if you're busy spinning waiting for the status to change, that's bad (though unlikely not the cause of the delay).

Comment: Show us the code for the thread.

Comment: @nos: Well, the status checking occurs during my main program loop, so it still checks for user input, handles events, etc. so the 'idling' is intentional (since I need these resources to continue), but the reason I'm using threads is because I don't want to have the window freeze and be unresponsive for that time.

Comment: Why do you join the thread at all? What's the point? If your main window sees that the thread's status is 'finished', isn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely it does not take two seconds to join a thread (assuming the system is not overloaded in general).  The waiting time you're seeing is presumably caused by some other work being done either in the children after they notify the parent, or in the parent while it polls for notifications from the children.

Comment: I haven't checked it yet, but I was looking through the code, and I'm kicking myself in the head. I realized that after the last line, there's still a destructor to be called for the large JSON tree that was generated in the thread.

Came back here and saw your answer which confirmed it. Thanks.